# Says only 1 error on last line ".class" expected

Tags: java, class, oop

I'm getting an error on the last line.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Stillgrinding{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        double  n = 25.0 /4;
        System.out.println(25.0 / 4);
        System.out.print("25.0 / 4 " + is + double);
        //I want the program to say 25.0 / 4 is 6.25
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `System.out.print("25.0 / 4 " + is + double);` to `System.out.print("25.0 / 4 " + "is" + n);`.

`n` is a variable of type `double`. You have to access it by it's variable name, `n`, not by it's type.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you are a beginner. But don't worry, everyone was once a beginner. in the first line of `main`, declared a variable called `n` and then you want to use it a few lines later. So far so good. But when you use it, i.e. this line:

```
System.out.print("25.0 / 4 " + is + double);
```

the syntax is not correct. I don't know why did you write `"25.0 / 4 " + is` when you can just write "25.0 / 4 is". See? And also, it seems that you don't know how to use a variable. If the variable is called `n` then just write `n`! `double` is the *type* of the variable. Just like in real life, you wouldn't call people "person" or "male" or "female". You call their *names*!

So the correct code is this:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    double  n = 25.0 /4;
    System.out.println(25.0 / 4);
    System.out.print("25.0 / 4 is " + n);
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys, yes I am a beginner aha. Appreciate the help.

Comment: It would be very nice if you can accept my answer. Just click on that tick. @MoizKhan

Answer (score 0):

here is your code fix your question

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Stillgrinding

    { public static void main(String [] args)

    {

    System.out.print("25.0 / 4 " + "is" + n);

    //I want the program to say 25.0 / 4 is 6.25
    } }
```